# JavaScript json.parse string error

Tags: javascript

I want to parse this string to an array

```
var string= "['one','two']";
var result= JSON.parse(string);
```

It throws an error

> `Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1'

I believe my approach is right I just can't figure out why its throwing that error.

Comment: Use double quotes in your JSON.

Comment: You can't define a string with single quotes in JSON. You need to use double quotes. See the diagram from the spec: http://i.stack.imgur.com/15Kqv.gif

Comment: http://www.json.org

Comment: What you're parsing is not JSON. Use a JSON syntax checker first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double quotes:

```
var string = '["one", "two"]';
```

You can't use single quote in a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it like this

```
var string= '["one","two"]';
var result= JSON.parse(string);
```

Json standard requires that the string have double quotes inside.